# WSO2IS 5.3.0 smtp email adapter force tls 1.2

Tags: smtp, tls1.2, wso2-identity-server

on our instance of wso2 Identity Server we have correctly set up registration confirmation emails and password recovery emails in **output-event-adapters.xml** in the `<adapterConfig type="email">` section .

Our smtp service provider now is going to move to TLS version 1.2 as minimum requirement (lower versions wil be deprecated soon).

Is there a way to force wso2 to use the 1.2 version of the TLS protocol ? I've searched but didn't find anytinhg .

Answer (score 0):

Seems the server reads and passes all the SMTP properties defined in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/output-event-adapters.xml` file's `email` adapter configs to the SMTP conncetion.

Therefore, you can try below Java mail properties.

1. `mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`
2. `mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2`

```
    <adapterConfig type="email">
        ...
        <property key="mail.smtp.ssl.protocols">1.2</property>
        <property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</property>
        ...
    </adapterConfig>
```

If this is Identity Server 5.9.0 or higher, changes should be done in the `deployment.toml` file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I've already tried adding these parameters but the mail is always sent out using  TLS 1.0 . We are on WSO2 IS 5.3.0, java 1.8 ...

Comment: Since you are using 5.3.0, I'm not sure if you are using the axis2 `maiTo` transport to send mails. Check if you have the `mailto` transport sender uncommented in the `axis2.xml` file. If so, please move the above suggested configurations under that tag.
`<transportSender name="mailto"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">`