# How to set TLS 1.1 in WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.1?

Tags: configuration, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to send mails to reset password in WSO2 Identity Server. The mail account server to send mails uses the 1.1 version of the TLS protocol. How can I set TLS 1.1 for mail transport in the file called "deployment.toml"?

I have tried to modify the files "<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/output-event-adapters.xml" and "<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml", but when I restart the server both files are overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64232807/10055162 in IS-5.10.0, these are the deployment.toml configs to add.

To enable "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": (NOTE: If you have already define [output_adapter.email] tag in the deployment.toml add the config under the same tag. Don't duplicate the tag in square brackets.)

```
[output_adapter.email]
enable_start_tls = true
```

To define "mail.smtp.ssl.protocols": (NOTE: If you have already define [output_adapter.email.custom_properties] tag in the deployment.toml add the config under the same tag. Don't duplicate the tag in square brackets.)

```
[output_adapter.email.custom_properties]
"mail.smtp.ssl.protocols"="TLSv1.1"
```